# how to make a data frame, if all of our data be in only 2 columns?

Tags: python, database

I have e question. assume you have a a dataframe like this:

| index | id1 | id2 | dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | c1 | c1 | 0 |
| 1 | c1 | c2 | 1 |
| 2 | c1 | c3 | 5 |
| 3 | c1 | c4 | 7 |
| 4 | c2 | c1 | 8 |
| 5 | c2 | c2 | 0 |
| 6 | c2 | c3 | 5 |
| 7 | c2 | c4 | 6 |
| 8 | c3 | c1 | 3 |
| 9 | c3 | c2 | 2 |
| 10 | c3 | c3 | 0 |
| 11 | c3 | c4 | 4 |
| 12 | c4 | c1 | 6 |
| 13 | c4 | c2 | 5 |
| 14 | c4 | c3 | 4 |
| 15 | c4 | c4 | 0 |

and want to convert it to another dataframe as below:

| index | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 7 |
| c2 | 8 | 0 | 5 | 6 |
| c3 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| c4 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 0 |

how can i do it in python?
please help me to solve this problem.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

with pandas you can do a pivot:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df="""
index   id1     id2     dist
0   c1  c1  0
1   c1  c2  1
2   c1  c3  5
3   c1  c4  7
4   c2  c1  8
5   c2  c2  0
6   c2  c3  5
7   c2  c4  6
8   c3  c1  3
9   c3  c2  2
10  c3  c3  0
11  c3  c4  4
12  c4  c1  6
13  c4  c2  5
14  c4  c3  4
15  c4  c4  0
"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')

dfPivot=pd.pivot(df,values='dist', index='id1', columns='id2')
print(dfPivot)
```

result:

```
id2  c1  c2  c3  c4
id1                
c1    0   1   5   7
c2    8   0   5   6
c3    3   2   0   4
c4    6   5   4   0
```

Comment: excuse me in this method, I have to define my data frame in string mode. is there another way to do this process directly on my original data frame ?

Comment: no, you have many ways to create dataframe (from a dictionnary, from excel file, from csv, ...) you can find all ways to create a dataframe by searching in google. I did like that to put your sample data in the script.